# mongodb group values by multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

For example, I have these documents:

```
{
  "addr": "address1",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address2",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address1",
  "book": "book5"
},
{
  "addr": "address3",
  "book": "book9"
},
{
  "addr": "address2",
  "book": "book5"
},
{
  "addr": "address2",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address1",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address15",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address9",
  "book": "book99"
},
{
  "addr": "address90",
  "book": "book33"
},
{
  "addr": "address4",
  "book": "book3"
},
{
  "addr": "address5",
  "book": "book1"
},
{
  "addr": "address77",
  "book": "book11"
},
{
  "addr": "address1",
  "book": "book1"
}
```

and so on.
How can I make a request, which will describe the top N addresses and the top M books per address?
Example of expected result:
 address1 | book_1: 5
          | book_2: 10
          | book_3: 50
          | total: 65
 ______________________
 address2 | book_1: 10
          | book_2: 10
          |...
          | book_M: 10
          | total: M*10
...
 ______________________
 addressN | book_1: 20
          | book_2: 20
          |...
          | book_M: 20
          | total: M*20

Answer (score 330, accepted):

### TLDR Summary

In modern MongoDB releases you can brute force this with [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) just off the basic aggregation result. For "large" results, run parallel queries instead for each grouping ( a demonstration listing is at the end of the answer ), or wait for [SERVER-9377](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377) to resolve, which would allow a "limit" to the number of items to `$push` to an array.

```js
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "addr": "$addr",
            "book": "$book"
        },
        "bookCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.addr",
        "books": { 
            "$push": { 
                "book": "$_id.book",
                "count": "$bookCount"
            },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$bookCount" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 },
    { "$project": {
        "books": { "$slice": [ "$books", 2 ] },
        "count": 1
    }}
])
```

---

### MongoDB 3.6 Preview

Still not resolving [SERVER-9377](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377), but in this release [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) allows a new "non-correlated" option which takes an `"pipeline"` expression as an argument instead of the `"localFields"` and `"foreignFields"` options. This then allows a "self-join" with another pipeline expression, in which we can apply [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) in order to return the "top-n" results.

```js
db.books.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$addr",
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 2 },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "books",
    "let": {
      "addr": "$_id"
    },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { 
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$addr", "$$addr"] }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$book",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "count": -1  } },
      { "$limit": 2 }
    ],
    "as": "books"
  }}
])
```

The other addition here is of course the ability to interpolate the variable through `$expr` using [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to select the matching items in the "join", but the general premise is a "pipeline within a pipeline" where the inner content can be filtered by matches from the parent. Since they are both "pipelines" themselves we can [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) each result separately.

This would be the next best option to running parallel queries, and actually would be better if the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) were allowed and able to use an index in the "sub-pipeline" processing. So which is does not use the "limit to `$push`" as the referenced issue asks, it actually delivers something that should work better.

---

### Original Content

You seem have stumbled upon the top "N" problem. In a way your problem is fairly easy to solve though not with the exact limiting that you ask for:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "addr": "$addr",
            "book": "$book"
        },
        "bookCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.addr",
        "books": { 
            "$push": { 
                "book": "$_id.book",
                "count": "$bookCount"
            },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$bookCount" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 }
])
```

Now that will give you a result like this:

```js
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "address1",
                    "books" : [
                            {
                                    "book" : "book4",
                                    "count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "book" : "book5",
                                    "count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "book" : "book1",
                                    "count" : 3
                            }
                    ],
                    "count" : 5
            },
            {
                    "_id" : "address2",
                    "books" : [
                            {
                                    "book" : "book5",
                                    "count" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "book" : "book1",
                                    "count" : 2
                            }
                    ],
                    "count" : 3
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

So this differs from what you are asking in that, while we do get the top results for the address values the underlying "books" selection is not limited to only a required amount of results.

This turns out to be very difficult to do, but it can be done though the complexity just increases with the number of items you need to match. To keep it simple we can keep this at 2 matches at most:

```js
db.books.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "addr": "$addr",
            "book": "$book"
        },
        "bookCount": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.addr",
        "books": { 
            "$push": { 
                "book": "$_id.book",
                "count": "$bookCount"
            },
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$bookCount" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
    { "$limit": 2 },
    { "$unwind": "$books" },
    { "$sort": { "count": 1, "books.count": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "books": { "$push": "$books" },
        "count": { "$first": "$count" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "books": "$books",
            "count": "$count"
        },
        "newBooks": "$books"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$newBooks" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "num1": { "$first": "$newBooks" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "newBooks": "$_id.books",
        "num1": 1
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$newBooks" },
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "num1": 1,
        "newBooks": 1,
        "seen": { "$eq": [
            "$num1",
            "$newBooks"
        ]}
    }},
    { "$match": { "seen": false } },
    { "$group":{
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "num1": { "$first": "$num1" },
        "num2": { "$first": "$newBooks" },
        "count": { "$first": "$_id.count" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "num1": 1,
        "num2": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "type": { "$cond": [ 1, [true,false],0 ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$type" },
    { "$project": {
        "books": { "$cond": [
            "$type",
            "$num1",
            "$num2"
        ]},
        "count": 1
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "count": { "$first": "$count" },
        "books": { "$push": "$books" }
    }},
    { "$sort": { "count": -1 } }
])
```

So that will actually give you the top 2 "books" from the top two "address" entries.

But for my money, stay with the first form and then simply "slice" the elements of the array that are returned to take the first "N" elements.

---

### Demonstration Code

The demonstration code is appropriate for usage with current LTS versions of NodeJS from v8.x and v10.x releases. That's mostly for the `async/await` syntax, but there is nothing really within the general flow that has any such restriction, and adapts with little alteration to plain promises or even back to plain callback implementation.

**index.js**

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const fs = require('mz/fs');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri);

    const db = client.db('bookDemo');
    const books = db.collection('books');

    let { version } = await db.command({ buildInfo: 1 });
    version = parseFloat(version.match(new RegExp(/(?:(?!-).)*/))[0]);

    // Clear and load books
    await books.deleteMany({});

    await books.insertMany(
      (await fs.readFile('books.json'))
        .toString()
        .replace(/\n$/,"")
        .split("\n")
        .map(JSON.parse)
    );

    if ( version >= 3.6 ) {

    // Non-correlated pipeline with limits
      let result = await books.aggregate([
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$addr",
          "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
        { "$limit": 2 },
        { "$lookup": {
          "from": "books",
          "as": "books",
          "let": { "addr": "$_id" },
          "pipeline": [
            { "$match": {
              "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$addr", "$$addr" ] }
            }},
            { "$group": {
              "_id": "$book",
              "count": { "$sum": 1 },
            }},
            { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 2 }
          ]
        }}
      ]).toArray();

      log({ result });
    }

    // Serial result procesing with parallel fetch

    // First get top addr items
    let topaddr = await books.aggregate([
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$addr",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
      { "$limit": 2 }
    ]).toArray();

    // Run parallel top books for each addr
    let topbooks = await Promise.all(
      topaddr.map(({ _id: addr }) =>
        books.aggregate([
          { "$match": { addr } },
          { "$group": {
            "_id": "$book",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
          }},
          { "$sort": { "count": -1 } },
          { "$limit": 2 }
        ]).toArray()
      )
    );

    // Merge output
    topaddr = topaddr.map((d,i) => ({ ...d, books: topbooks[i] }));
    log({ topaddr });

    client.close();

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

**books.json**

```js
{ "addr": "address1",  "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address2",  "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address1",  "book": "book5"  }
{ "addr": "address3",  "book": "book9"  }
{ "addr": "address2",  "book": "book5"  }
{ "addr": "address2",  "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address1",  "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address15", "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address9",  "book": "book99" }
{ "addr": "address90", "book": "book33" }
{ "addr": "address4",  "book": "book3"  }
{ "addr": "address5",  "book": "book1"  }
{ "addr": "address77", "book": "book11" }
{ "addr": "address1",  "book": "book1"  }
```

Comment: Apparently in MongoDB 5.0, sub-pipelines within $lookup can use indexes for matching under certain conditions ($eq/$lt/$lte/$gt/$gte operators; no multikey indexes; can't compare to an array or undefined; no more than one field path).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `TLDR` will not work without sorting the books before the second grouping, as nothing promises that these are the `topM` books

Comment: the resolution status of `SERVER-9377` is `Fixed`

Comment: You don't need to use object when listing keys, just use array of "$key_name" values instead.

Answer (score 79):

Using aggregate function like below :

```
[
{$group: {_id : {book : '$book',address:'$addr'}, total:{$sum :1}}},
{$project : {book : '$_id.book', address : '$_id.address', total : '$total', _id : 0}}
]
```

it will give you result like following :

```
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book33",
            "address" : "address90"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book5",
            "address" : "address1"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book99",
            "address" : "address9"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book1",
            "address" : "address5"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book5",
            "address" : "address2"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book3",
            "address" : "address4"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book11",
            "address" : "address77"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book9",
            "address" : "address3"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 1,
            "book" : "book1",
            "address" : "address15"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 2,
            "book" : "book1",
            "address" : "address2"
        }, 
        {
            "total" : 3,
            "book" : "book1",
            "address" : "address1"
        }
```

I didn't quite get your expected result format, so feel free to modify this to one you need.

Comment: That only solves part of the problem, and doesn't do "top" for the two groupings.

Comment: Moreover on the comment from @WiredPrairie I cannot see how this even solved any part of the question that was presented. "The top N addresses and the top N books per address".

Comment: pls help if you can for related questions in mongoDB - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067856/calculate-dwell-time-between-2-statuses-of-a-field

Comment: Title says _mongodb group values by multiple fields_ and exactly that is I am interested in. `{$group: {_id: {book: '$book', address: '$addr'}, ...` gives the answer to this question. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 15):

Below query will provide exactly the same result as given in the desired response:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { addresses: "$addr", books: "$book" },
            num: { $sum :1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.addresses",
            bookCounts: { $push: { bookName: "$_id.books",count: "$num" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            bookCounts:1,
            "totalBookAtAddress": {
                "$sum": "$bookCounts.count"
            }
        }
    }

])
```

The response will be looking like below:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "address4",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book3",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "address90",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book33",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "address15",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book1",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "address3",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book9",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "address5",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book1",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : "address1",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book1",
            "count" : 3
        },
        {
            "bookName" : "book5",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 4
},

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : "address2",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book1",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "bookName" : "book5",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 3
},

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : "address77",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book11",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
},

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : "address9",
    "bookCounts" : [
        {
            "bookName" : "book99",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "totalBookAtAddress" : 1
}
```

Comment: is it possible to sort elements in the "booksCounts" list of each group? This answer really helped me to aggregate some data but instead of bookName, I have dates and I would like to sort data in each group by date

Answer (score 7):

**Since mongoDB version 3.6** this is easy to do, using `$group`, `$slice`, `$limit`, and `$sort`:

1. `$group` the books to count them
2. `$sort` so they will be later pushed according to count
3. `$group` by `address`, `$push` relevant books, and `$sum` the total per address.
4. `$sort` by address total
5. `$limit` the address results to `topN`
6. Limit the books in the array to `topM` using `$slice`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: {book: "$book",  addr: "$addr"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$sort: {"_id.addr": 1, count: -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.addr", totalCount: {$sum: "$count"}, 
      books: {$push: {book: "$_id.book", count: "$count"}}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {totalCount: -1}},
  {$limit: topN},
  {$set: {addr: "$_id", _id: "$$REMOVE", books: {$slice: ["$books", 0, topM]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example-v3.4](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_B0tvt66tFU)

**On mongoDB version 5.2** there is a `topN` accumulator that can simplify even more:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: {book: "$book",  addr: "$addr"}, count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.addr",
      totalCount: {$sum: "$count"},
      books: {$topN: {output: {book: "$_id.book", count: "$count"},
                      sortBy: {count: -1},
                      n: topM
      }}
  }},
  {$sort: {totalCount: -1}},
  {$limit: topN},
  {$project: {addr: "$_id", _id: 0, books: 1, totalCount: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example-v5.2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D6-Z0yOLIs_)