# mongoDB c# query to return most recent versions of documents grouped by multiple fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following collection:

```
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1", "version": 1}
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1 updated","version": 2}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2", "version": 1}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated","version": 2}
```

Each time a new item needs to be added with the same "name" and "type" a new version will be created. For example, if I need to add:

```
 { "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated again" }
```

Then my updated collection will look like:

```
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1", "version": 1}
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1 updated","version": 2}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2", "version": 1}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated","version": 2}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated again","version": 3}
```

What I want is to implement a query that returns the most recent versions of elements, unless a specific version is specified.

So by default the query should return:

```
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1 updated","version": 2}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated again","version": 3}
```

Or if I specify a version, e.g. 2, then it should return:

```
{ "name": "name 1", "type": 1, description: "desc 1 updated","version": 2}
{ "name": "name 2", "type": 1, description: "desc 2 updated","version": 2}
```

So far I've reached the point where I can get the count grouped by one field:

```
_mongoDB.Collection.Aggregate()
                        .Match(filter)
                        .Group(new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    { "_id", "$name"}, 
                                    { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1)}
                                });
```

So far I built the filters using the [Filter Definition Builder](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/).

Comment: What queries have you tried?

Comment: This looks pretty much like the top-N grouping requirement discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields