# mongodb group by multiple keys values vise versa

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a user collection with following data

```
    [
  {
    "user_id": "5625c95ac2d34f27148b64fa",
    "friend_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "562744ccc2d34f27148b6eb7",
    "friend_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "56248eb9c2d34f2f148b5a18",
    "friend_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c",
    "friend_id": "561f3e06c2d34f27148b45f6"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c",
    "friend_id": "5620de97c2d34f2f148b578f"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "56276b52c2d34f27148b7128",
    "friend_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
  },
  {
    "user_id": "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c",
    "friend_id": "56276b52c2d34f27148b7128"
  }
]
```

i need to fetch the documents in which combination of `user_id` and `friend_id` not repeated. i.e in the above example last two documents `user_id` repeated in `friend_id` of next document.

I tried with mongo aggrigate and group by but could not reduce it.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields

Comment: here i need eliminate documents in which user_id and friend_id repeated vise versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this you basically need to combine both `user_id` and `friend_id` values in a uniquely sorted combination. This means creating an array for each document with those members and sorting that array so that the order is always the same.

Then you can `$group` on that sorted array content to see which documents contain that same combination and then only return those that do not share that same combination.

This leads to this aggregate statement:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "friend_id": 1,
        "combined": {
            "$map": {
                "input": ["A","B"],
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [ 
                        { "$eq": [ "$$el", "A" ] },
                        "$user_id",
                        "$friend_id"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }            
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$sort": { "combined": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "combined": { "$push": "$combined" },
        "user_id": { "$first": "$user_id" },
        "friend_id": { "$first": "$friend_id"  }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined",
        "docs": { "$push": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "user_id": "$user_id",
            "friend_id": "$friend_id"
        }}
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$docs" }, 1] },
            "then": "$$PRUNE",
            "else": "$$KEEP"
        }
    }}
])
```

The PHP translation for laravel means to need to access the raw collection object from the manager, where "collection" is the actual name of the collection in MongoDB:

```
$result = DB::collection("collection")->raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate(
        array(
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'user_id' => 1,
                    'friend_id' => 1,
                    'combined' => array(
                        '$map' => array(
                            'input' => array("A","B"),
                            'as' => 'el',
                            'in' => array(
                                '$cond' => array(
                                    array( '$eq' => array( '$el', 'A' ) ),
                                    '$user_id',
                                    '$friend_id'
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array( '$unwind' =>'$combined' ),
            array( '$sort' => array( 'combined' => 1 ) ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$_id',
                    'combined' => array( '$push' => '$combined' ),
                    'user_id' => array( '$first' => '$user_id' ),
                    'friend_id' => array( '$first' => '$friend_id' )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$combined',
                    'docs' => array(
                        '$push' => array(
                            '_id' => '$_id',
                            'user_id' => '$user_id',
                            'friend_id' => 'friend_id'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$redact' => array(
                    '$cond' => array(
                        'if' => array( '$ne' => array( array( '$size' => '$docs'), 1) ),
                        'then' => '$$PRUNE',
                        'else' => '$$KEEP'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
});
```

Or if your MongoDB version is less than 2.6, and you lack operators like `$map` and `$redact`, then you can still do this, but not as efficiently:

```
$result = DB::collection("collection")->raw(function($collection) {
    return $collection->aggregate(
        array(
            array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'user_id' => 1,
                    'friend_id' => 1,
                    'type' => array( '$const' => array( 'A', 'B' ) )
                )
            ),
            array( '$unwind' => '$type' ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$_id',
                    'user_id' => array( '$first' => '$user_id' ),
                    'friend_id' => array( '$first' => '$friend_id' ),
                    'combined' => array( 
                        '$push' => array(
                            '$cond' => array(
                                array( '$eq' => array( '$type', 'A' ) ),
                                '$user_id',
                                '$friend_id'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            array( '$unwind' =>'$combined' ),
            array( '$sort' => array( 'combined' => 1 ) ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$_id',
                    'combined' => array( '$push' => '$combined' ),
                    'user_id' => array( '$first' => '$user_id' ),
                    'friend_id' => array( '$first' => '$friend_id' )
                )
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => '$combined',
                    'docs' => array(
                        '$push' => array(
                            '_id' => '$_id',
                            'user_id' => '$user_id',
                            'friend_id' => 'friend_id'
                        )
                    ),
                    'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
                )
            ),
            array( '$match' => array( 'count' => 1 ) )
        )
    );
});
```

Where the first three stages mimic what the first stage is doing in the first example listing by putting both values in a single array. Of course the last two stages by "counting" the array members while grouping and then filtering out anything that does not have a "count" of `1`.

In either case this leaves you with output that only lists the documents where that combination does not occur in either order:

```
{ 
    "_id" : [ "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c", "5625c95ac2d34f27148b64fa" ], 
    "docs" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56306f6cd2387ad4c95b0cc9"),
            "user_id" : "5625c95ac2d34f27148b64fa",
            "friend_id" : "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c" 
        } 
    ] 
}
{ 
    "_id" : [ "561f3e06c2d34f27148b45f6", "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c" ], 
    "docs" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56306f6cd2387ad4c95b0ccc"), 
            "user_id" : "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c",
            "friend_id" : "561f3e06c2d34f27148b45f6"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : [ "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c", "56248eb9c2d34f2f148b5a18" ], 
    "docs" : [
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56306f6cd2387ad4c95b0ccb"), 
            "user_id" : "56248eb9c2d34f2f148b5a18", 
            "friend_id" : "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : [ "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c", "5620de97c2d34f2f148b578f" ],
    "docs" : [
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56306f6cd2387ad4c95b0ccd"), 
            "user_id" : "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c", 
            "friend_id" : "5620de97c2d34f2f148b578f"
        }
    ]
}
{ 
    "_id" : [ "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c", "562744ccc2d34f27148b6eb7" ], 
    "docs" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56306f6cd2387ad4c95b0cca"), 
            "user_id" : "562744ccc2d34f27148b6eb7", 
            "friend_id" : "561f40bac2d34f17148b462c"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can pretty up the output, but this serves the purpose of showing the ordered combination used along with the original document data.

Comment: when i tried this in mongo shell it's working file, but when tried with laravel it is throwing this error "exception: the group aggregate field name '$_id' cannot be an operator name"

Comment: @RameshPaul That was a typo by me in the PHP listing. Corrected. It was shown correctly in the original listing as well as `"_id": "$combined"` which is where the typing mistake was.