# group by elements of subdocuments with Max N (3) Records in each group with pagination and overall total

Tags: spring, mongodb, pagination, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have some sample data stored in mongodb 3.2 as given below and want a mongodb / spring-data-mongodb aggregation query to group by elements of subdocuments with Max N (3) Records in each group with pagination and overall total.

```
**Book Name, Revenue , units sold, Book Categories**
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747f8"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test6","revenue":10.0,"unitsSold":1,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747f9"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":11.0,"unitsSold":2,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fa"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":12.0,"unitsSold":3,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fb"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":13.0,"unitsSold":4,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fc"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":14.0,"unitsSold":5,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fd"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":15.0,"unitsSold":6,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747fe"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test10","revenue":16.0,"unitsSold":7,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5808578b33fa6f161c9747ff"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test11","revenue":100.0,"unitsSold":100,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages/Bartending"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Taste"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e462"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":20.0,"unitsSold":10,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e463"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":19.0,"unitsSold":9,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e464"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":18.0,"unitsSold":8,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e465"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":17.0,"unitsSold":7,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e466"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":16.0,"unitsSold":6,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
 {"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e467"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test1","revenue":15.0,"unitsSold":5,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e468"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test2","revenue":14.0,"unitsSold":4,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e469"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test3","revenue":13.0,"unitsSold":3,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e46a"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test4","revenue":12.0,"unitsSold":2,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
{"_id":{"$oid":"580857b833fa6f0c3499e46b"},"_class":"exceltest.TestBean","bookName":"Test5","revenue":11.0,"unitsSold":1,"bookCategory":[{"categoryCode":"Cooking/"},{"categoryCode":"Cooking/Beverages"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/"},{"categoryCode":"Food Receipe/Bartending"}]}
```

---

```
aggregate query Needed the output in this for categoryCode :"COOKING"
Overall Total Revenue : 263
Overall units sold : 91
Cooking/Beverages
/* 3 top book names for category Cooking/Beverages sorted in descending order*/

Book Name  |       Total Revenue | Total units
Test11     |                 100 | 100
Test1      |                 46  | 17
Test2      |                 45  | 16
/* Next 3 top book names in descending order with pagination*/
Test3      |                 44  | 15
Test4      |                 43  | 14
Test5      |                 42  | 13
/* Next 3 top book names in descending order with Pagination*/
Test10     |                 16  | 7

/* 3 top book names for Cooking/Beverages/Bartending sorted in descending order*/

Book Name  |       Total Revenue | Total units
Test11     |                 100 | 100
Test1      |                 46  | 17
Test2      |                 45  | 16
/* Next 3 top book names in descending order with pagination*/
Test3      |                 44  | 15
Test4      |                 43  | 14
Test5      |                 42  | 13
/* Next 3 top book names in descending order with pagination*/
Test10     |                 16  | 7
```

I have tried this link [mongodb group values by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields) 
Sample query I tried is :

```
 db.books.aggregate([
{$match:{'bookCategory.categoryCode' : 'Cooking/'}},
 {$unwind:'$bookCategory'},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": {
        "categoryCode": "$bookCategory.categoryCode",
        "book": "$bookName"
    },
    "revenue": { $sum:"$revenue" },
     "unitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
}
 }
,
{$match:{'_id.categoryCode' : {$regex : 'Cooking/'}}},
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.categoryCode",


    "books": { 
        "$push": { 
          //  "category": "$_id.categoryCode",
    "book":"$_id.book",
    "revenue": { $sum:"$revenue" },
     "unitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
        },
    },
    "topRevenue": { $sum: "$revenue" },
    "topUnitsSold": { $sum:"$unitsSold" }
}},
{ "$sort": { "topRevenue": -1 } },
{ "$limit": 3},

{ "$project": {
    "books": { "$slice": [ "$books", 3 ] },
    "topRevenue": 1,
    "topUnitsSold": 1
}}
```

])

The output is as follows :

```
{
"_id" : "Cooking/",
"books" : [ 
    {
        "book" : "Test6",
        "revenue" : 10,
        "unitsSold" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test1",
        "revenue" : 46,
        "unitsSold" : 17
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test4",
        "revenue" : 43,
        "unitsSold" : 14
    }
],
"topRevenue" : 263,
"topUnitsSold" : 91
}

{
"_id" : "Cooking/Beverages",
"books" : [ 
    {
        "book" : "Test6",
        "revenue" : 10,
        "unitsSold" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test1",
        "revenue" : 46,
        "unitsSold" : 17
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test2",
        "revenue" : 45,
        "unitsSold" : 16
    }
],
"topRevenue" : 263,
"topUnitsSold" : 91
}

{
"_id" : "Cooking/Beverages/Bartending",
"books" : [ 
    {
        "book" : "Test6",
        "revenue" : 10,
        "unitsSold" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test2",
        "revenue" : 12,
        "unitsSold" : 3
    }, 
    {
        "book" : "Test1",
        "revenue" : 11,
        "unitsSold" : 2
    }
],
"topRevenue" : 108,
"topUnitsSold" : 36
}
```

but I am NOT successful in getting the desired result.

Please lemme know about the feasibility of this requirement in mongodb.

Please help.

Regards
Kris

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: @sidgate please see the updated question and the query I tried, was not successful. Please help. Regards, Kris