# Aggregation on multi field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Reading MongoDb documentation about `aggregation` operation, I've found [**this**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```
db.orders.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { status: "A" } },
        { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
        { $sort: { total: -1 } }
    ],
    {
         explain: true
    }
```

)

But, suppose I have another field named `phone`, how can I aggregate about `cust_id` and `phone`?

I've tried as follow:

```
{ $group: { _id: {"$cust_id", "$phone"}, total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
```

But doesn't work

**EDIT**

I want this behaviour:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM orders
GROUP BY cust_id, phone
```

But I have this error (I must attach screenshot because by MongoChef I can't textual error):

[image]

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a problem statement. What you expect, and what you get instead?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to explain. It's just wrong syntax. Objects should have field names, not only field values. E.g.:

```
{ $group: { _id: {id:"$cust_id", phone:"$phone"}, total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
```

Comment: Thanks! It's very simple, my fault!