# Robmongo - aggregate values distinct by other value\cloumn

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to robmongo and I received an assignment to write some queries.

let say I have a collection that each key has some values for example value of "userId" and value of "deviceModel".
I need to write a query that shows for each device model how many users has this device.
this is what I got so far:

db.device_data.aggregate([   {"$group" : {_id:"$data.deviceModel", count:{$sum:1}}}])

The problem is that this aggregate for each device the number of keys it appears.

```
{
"_id" : { "$binary" : "AN6GmE7Thi+Sd/dpLRjIilgsV/4AAAg=", "$type" : "00" },
"auditVersion" : "1.0",
"currentTime" : NumberLong(1479301118381),
"data" : {
    "deviceDesign" : "bullhead",
    "loginType" : "GOOGLE",
    "source" : "SDKLoader",
    "systemUptimeMillis" : 137652880.0,
    "simCountryIso" : "il",
    "networkOperatorName" : "Cellcom",
    "hasPhonePermission" : true,
    "deviceIdentifier" : "353627074839559",
    "sdkVersion" : "0.7.939.2016-11-14.masterDev",
    "brand" : "google",
    "osVersion" : "7.0",
    "osVersionIncremental" : "3239497",
    "deviceModel" : "Nexus 5X",
    "deviceSDKVersion" : 24.0,
    "manufacturer" : "LGE",
    "sdkShortBuildDate" : "2016-11-14",
    "sdkFullBuildDate" : "Mon Nov 14 22:16:40 IST 2016",
    "product" : "bullhead"
},
"timezone" : "Asia/Jerusalem",
"collectionAlias" : "DEVICE_DATA",
"shortDate" : 17121,
"userId" : "00DE86984ED3862F9277F7692D18C88A@1927cc81cfcf7a467e9d4f4ac7a1534b"}
```

this is an example of how one key locks like.

Comment: Show your sample document. Change the sum : 1 to $sum : "$userid"... if I got your doc structure correctly..

Comment: now, the count is 0 for all the deviceModel

Comment: Try to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query should give you distinct count of `userId` for a `deviceModel`. I meant if a same `userId` present for a `deviceModel` multiple items, it will be counted only once.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ {"$group" : {_id:"$data.deviceModel", userIds:{$addToSet: "$userId"}}
},
{
    $unwind:"$userIds"
},
{
    $group: { _id: "$_id", userIdCount: { $sum:1} }
}])
```

**Unwind:-**

> Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a
>   document for each element.

In the above solution, it deconstructs the `userId` array formed on the first pipeline.

**addToSet:-**

> Returns an array of all unique values that results from applying an
>   expression to each document in a group of documents that share the
>   same group by key.

This function ensures that only unique values are added to an array. In the above case, the `userId` is added to an array in the first pipeline.

Comment: First of all, thanks! can you give a short explanation of what unwind and addToSet does?