# Finding top N entries from the Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My collection is structured like this:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "Trips": [
        {
            "EndID": 5,
            "Tripcount": 12
        },
        {
            "EndID": 6,
            "Tripcount": 19
        }
     ],
     "_id": 2,
     "Trips": [
        {
            "EndID": 4,
            "Tripcount": 12
        },
        {
            "EndID": 5,
            "Tripcount": 19
        }
     ], ...
}
```

As it can be seen, every document has a `Trips` array. Now what I want to find, is the **top N Tripcounts of all the `Trips` arrays combined** across the documents in the collection. Is that possible?

I already have the following, however this only takes the **single** greatest `Tripcount` from each `Trips` array and then outputs 50 of them. So actually having the top 2 trips in one `Trips` array results in this query dropping the second one:

```
var group = db.eplat1.aggregate([
  {   "$unwind": "$Trips"},
  {   "$sort": {
          "Trips.Tripcount": -1
  }
  },
  {   "$limit": 50 },
  {   "$group": {
        "_id": 1,
        "Trips": {
          "$push": {
            "Start": "$_id",
            "Trips": "$Trips"
          }
        }
  }}
  ], {allowDiskUse: true})
```

Note that I believe this problem is different to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields), as there only one document is given.

Comment: So what is the question? You `$unwind` the arrays, so you have all entries. You `$sort` them so the counts are on top. Then you `$limit`, so that's 50 top entries. What more do you think you need?

Comment: @NeilLunn As described, having e.g. 2 of the top trips in one of the Trips arrays results in loosing this second top trip, as only the single top trip per `Trips` array gets output here.

Comment: So you want the "top 2" trips from "each array" in "every document"? Really your question is not as clear as you think it is so you really should answer.

Comment: No, I want the top N trips after you would combine all of the `Trips` arrays. My problem: Assume there are 2 documents and so 2 Trips arrays, first one contains 2 trips (count 5 and 6) and second one contains one trip with count of 4. This query above outputs 6 and 4 with limit of 2, not 6 and 5 as it should.

Comment: @NeilLunn Nvm, found it. Should be `"_id": "$_id"` and `"Start": "$_id"` should be `"End": "$EndID"` in the group stage. Yes I have 3.4.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to sort the array elements ([`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)/[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)/[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)) and  then you can do your [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) for the top values and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) the results.

Finally you [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) for the "top N" in the documents in the array.

```
db.eplat1.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$Trips" },
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "Tips.TripCount": -1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "Trips": { "$push": "$Trips" },
    "maxTrip": { "$max": "$Trips.TripCount" }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "maxTrip": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 50 },
  { "$addFields": { "Trips": { "$slice": [ "$Trips", 0 , 2 ] } } }
])
```