# how to aggregate my mongo data based on date filter

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongodb-query

i am mongodb beginner. Junior JavaScript developer using mongodb/mongoose
i wonder if anyone can help me for this easy challenge :i would like to group results based on dates ( i am able to group and able to filter by date but not both of them )

schema :

```
const ExpenseSchema = new Schema({
    item: String,
    amount: Number,
    date: Date,
    group: String,
})
```

enter code here

sample :

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "608c4fd352efae8cc8a10100"
  },
  "item": "Amril",
  "amount": 435.42,
  "date": {
    "$date": "2018-05-05T11:06:00.000Z"
  },
  "group": "food",
  "__v": 0
}
```

My NOT working mongoose query

```
enter code here

Expense.aggregate([
        {
            $match: 
            {
                date: { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }
            }
        },
         {
            $group:
            {
                _id: '$group',
                totalAmount: { $sum: "$amount" }
            }
        }], function (err, total) {
        res.send(total)
    })
```

thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gr9YQ.png)

Comment: see similar question [mongodb group values by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields) you an try something like `$group: { _id; { group: "$group", date: "$date" }, .. }`

Comment: you want to group data based on `date and group fields`?.

Comment: yes , i want to group the sum of amount for all expenses between given dates.

Answer (score 0):

solved - changed the query to :

```
Expense.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                date: { $gt: new Date(new Date(startDate).setHours(00, 00, 00)), $lt: new Date(new Date(endDate).setHours(23, 59, 59)) }
            }
        },{$group:{
            _id:'$group',
            amount:{$sum:'$amount'}
        }}
    ], function (err, total) {
        res.send(total)
    })

    
})
```

added :

```
 { $gt: new Date(new Date(startDate).setHours(00, 00, 00)), $lt: new Date(new Date(endDate).setHours(23, 59, 59)) }
```

instead of :

```
{ $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }
```

based on this article :
https://dev.to/itz_giddy/how-to-query-documents-in-mongodb-that-fall-within-a-specified-date-range-using-mongoose-and-node-524a