# MongoDB aggregate match by array of ObjectIds

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

**COLLECTION**

I have a collection abyssBattles with the following data:

```
[
  {
    "floor_level": "12-2",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565dc",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565e3",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956648",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956669"
    ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-3",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565dc",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565e3",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956648",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956669"
    ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-1",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565dc",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb419565e3",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956648",
      "60b6edd41ec85acb41956669"
    ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-1",
    "battle_index": 2,
    "party": [
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0c6",
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0d2",
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0e8",
      "60ba56671ec85acb41045ff5"
    ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-2",
    "battle_index": 2,
    "party": [
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0c6",
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0d2",
      "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0e8",
      "60ba56671ec85acb41045ff5"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm mainly filtering by `floor_level` and by `ObjectIds` in the `party` array. I'm try to aggregate records where `party` contains the exact same 4 `ObjectId`s (already sorted). I want to group these by the `floor_level` and `battle_index` they belong, and get sum the count for the `party`.

**DESIRED RESULT**

The result I'm trying to achieve would look like so:

```
[
  { 
    floor: "12-1-1",
    parties: [
     { 
       party: [
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0c6",
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0d2",
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0e8",
          "60ba56671ec85acb41045ff5"
       ],
       count: 23
     },
     { 
       party: [
        "60b6edd41ec85acb419565dc",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb419565e3",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb41956648",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb41956669"
       ],
       count: 13
     },
     ...
   ].
  },
  { 
    floor: "12-1-2",
    parties: [
     { 
       party: [
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0c6",
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0d2",
          "60b6ee621ec85acb4195b0e8",
          "60ba56671ec85acb41045ff5"
       ],
       count: 52
     },
     { 
       party: [
        "60b6edd41ec85acb419565dc",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb419565e3",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb41956648",
        "60b6edd41ec85acb41956669"
       ],
       count: 13
     },
     ...
   ]
  }
]
```

Where `count` represents the number of the specific `party` found for the respective `floor`. Each `floor` would have multiple `party` in an array, each `party` being a unique combination of 4 `ObjectId`s.

**EXAMPLE**

Let's say we have a simplified version of the collection here:

```
[
  {
    "floor_level": "12-1",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-1",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-1",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [ 1, 2, 4, 5]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-2",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [ 1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    "floor_level": "12-2",
    "battle_index": 1,
    "party": [ 1, 2, 4, 5]
  }
]
```

If I query for `floor_level`s [ "12-1", "12-2" ] I would expect to see this output:

```
[
  {
    "floor": "12-1",
    "parties": [
      { 
        "party": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
        "count": 1
      },
      { 
        "party": [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ],
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "floor": "12-2",
    "parties": [
      { 
        "party": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
        "count": 1
      },
      { 
        "party": [ 1, 2, 4, 5 ],
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**ATTEMPT**

I have tried referring to the resource here: [mongodb group values by multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields)

```
db.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "floor": { $concat: [$floor_level, $battle_index] },
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "party",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { 
        "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$party", "$$party"] }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "party": "$party",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "count": -1  } },
    ],
    "as": "parties"
  }}
])
```

But I found it harder to achieve my results with the slightly more complex structure of nested arrays and objects.

Comment: Can you also share sample input from both the collections and expected output based on the sample data along with logic you want to apply?

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form the updated expected output, hope this would help you

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { level: "$floor_level", party: "$party" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.level",
      "parties": {
        "$push": {
          party: "$_id.party",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LJ7Hp64sp5c)**

Suppose you need the battel index also to be grouped, you can use

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { level: "$floor_level", party: "$party", index:"$battle_index" },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": { "level": "$_id.level", "index": "$_id.index" },    
      "parties": {
        "$push": {
          party: "$_id.party",
          count: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      floor: { "$concat": [ "$_id.level", "-", { $toString: "$_id.index" } ] },
      _id: "$$REMOVE",
      index: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t-soBgLaqyF)**

Comment: Worked beautifully, thank you so much! Your use of `$group` was also much easier to follow than other methods I've seen.