# Mongodb Multiple Aggregate more than 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

So i have an mongodb data structure like below:

```
[
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.32.3.1",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750297,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.32.3.2",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750319,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.31.3.1",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750361,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.31.3.2",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750400,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.30.3.1",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750444,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.30.3.2",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750472,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.29.3.1",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750500,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 182,
    "Lokasi": "W.29.3.2",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680750533,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Pink",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 54,
    "Lokasi": "W.31.4.1",
    "Zona": "W",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "August-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-06",
    "expiredStatus": "Good",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 4,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680753064,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 108,
    "Lokasi": "A.10.3.1",
    "Zona": "A",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "August-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-07",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680831580,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 108,
    "Lokasi": "A.10.3.2",
    "Zona": "A",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-07",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680831598,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 44,
    "Lokasi": "A.9.1.1",
    "Zona": "A",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-07",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680831742,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 108,
    "Lokasi": "A.11.3.1",
    "Zona": "A",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-07",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680831771,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "Material": "309979",
    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
    "Type": "FG",
    "Status": "NPL",
    "Channel": "GT",
    "Country": "INDONESIA",
    "Activity": "Aging",
    "Lakban": "Kuning",
    "Gedung": "A",
    "Plant": "K120",
    "Jumlah": 108,
    "Lokasi": "A.11.3.2",
    "Zona": "A",
    "shelfLifeDB": 6,
    "expiredDate": "July-2023",
    "Transaction_Status": "verified",
    "Transaction_Date": "2023-04-07",
    "expiredStatus": "Near Expired",
    "ExpiredIn_months": 3,
    "ReAging": "N",
    "createdAt": 1680831790,
    "updatedAt": 1681428600,
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

as you can see above i want to aggregate it by 3 fields, Material, Transaction Date and The expired Date, at my first try i succeed to grouped it by Material and Transaction Date but i notice that eventhough it has more than one different expiredDate it not disctint it on the Response instead it groups it as one, so i try to aggregate by expiredDate also, here is my try:

```
if (req.body.search) {
        query.push({
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  Material: { $regex: req.body.search, $options: "i" },
                },
                {
                  Material_Description: {
                    $regex: req.body.search,
                    $options: "i",
                  },
                },
                {
                  Type: { $regex: req.body.search, $options: "i" },
                },
                {
                  Lokasi: { $regex: req.body.search, $options: "i" },
                },
                {
                  Expired_Date: { $regex: req.body.search, $options: "i" },
                },
                {
                  Channel: { $regex: req.body.search, $options: "i" },
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  Plant: plant,
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      Type: type,
                    },
                    {
                      $and: [
                        { Gedung: gedung },

                        {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              Transaction_Status: "verified",
                            },
                            {
                              $and: [
                                {
                                  Transaction_Date: {
                                    $lte: dateLists[0],
                                  },
                                },
                                {
                                  Transaction_Date: {
                                    $gte: dateLists.slice(-1).toString(),
                                  },
                                },
                              ],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        });
      } else {
        query.push({
          $and: [
            {
              Plant: plant,
            },
            {
              $and: [
                {
                  Type: type,
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    { Gedung: gedung },

                    {
                      $and: [
                        {
                          Transaction_Status: "verified",
                        },
                        {
                          $and: [
                            {
                              Transaction_Date: {
                                $lte: dateLists[0],
                              },
                            },
                            {
                              Transaction_Date: {
                                $gte: dateLists.slice(-1).toString(),
                              },
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        });
      }
      console.log(dateLists);
      const aggregate = TransactionFG.aggregate([
        {
          $match: query[0] ? query[0] : {},
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: {
              Material: "$Material",
              Transaction_Date: "$Transaction_Date",
            },
            Material_Description: {
              $first: "$Material_Description",
            },
            expiredDate: {
              $first: "$expiredDate",
            },
            y: {
              $sum: "$Jumlah",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.Material",
            Material_Description: {
              $first: "$Material_Description",
            },
            expiredDate: {
              $first: "$expiredDate",
            },
            data: {
              $push: {
                k: "$_id.Transaction_Date",
                v: "$y",
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$_id.expiredDate",
            Material_Description: {
              $first: "$Material_Description",
            },
            Material: {
              $first: "$Material",
     

   },
        datas: {
          $push: {
            k: "$_id.Transaction_Date",
            v: "$y",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
          $mergeObjects: [
            "$$ROOT",
            {
              $arrayToObject: "$data",
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $unset: "data",
    },
  ]);

  const data = await TransactionFG.aggregatePaginate(aggregate, options);
```

But instead of returning the result i hope i get this error:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Success Retrieving Data",
    "data": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "_id": null,
                "Material_Description": "NABATI RCO 125g MT (24pcs)",
                "Material": null,
                "datas": [
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    {}
                ]
            }
        ],
        "totalDocs": 1,
        "limit": 1000,
        "page": 1,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "pagingCounter": 1,
        "hasPrevPage": false,
        "hasNextPage": false,
        "prevPage": null,
        "nextPage": null
    }
}
```

Can someone pointing out where did i do wrong or where do i have to improve here?
my expected Value:

```
 {
                    "_id": "309979",
                    "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
                    "expiredDate": "August-2023",
                    "2023-04-07": 476,
                    "2023-04-06": 1510
                },
 {
                "_id": "309979",
                "Material_Description": "RICHEESE MIE GORENG KJ 74g  (40 pcs)",
                "expiredDate": "July-2023",
                "2023-04-07": 183,
            },
```

Comment: Have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22932364/mongodb-group-values-by-multiple-fields ?

Comment: @Kosmas yep as you can see above i have explained if there is only two fields i have done it but, when it comes to the third one the expiredDate, i got some problem thats why i handed on my try and what i expected

Comment: It seems that you are using $first for the Material and expiredDate fields in the final group stage, but those fields are not included in the _id grouping key.

Comment: any help on that sir? i still confused where i did wrong here... @Kosmas