# Find last message in coversation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have 2 schemas:

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    login: {type:String, unique: true, trim:true, index:true},
    password: String
)};

var MessageSchema   = new Schema({
    text: String,
    from_id: {type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user', index:true},
    to_id: {type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'user', index:true},
    date: Number
});
```

Now for example I have 4 users in the database. Assuming user1 sent 5 messages to each other user, user2 and user3 each replied to user1 message. Now I need to return only one recent message from each dialog. How can i do this?

Comment: Please give us example docs and your desired output based on those example docs. It's also helpful to include anything you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

One excellent way to do this would be by using MongoDB's aggregation framework.

I'm not 100% clear on your specific use-case, but I would think that using `$unwind` to get all of the messages in the same place, and then filtering by perhaps a `$setUnion` for uniqueness, then  a `$sort` and a `$limit` if you want it to only display the most recent messages.

Here's a link to the quick reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: i need to create messaging system. i have users, i have messages between them. but also i need to return dialogs for each user which consist of latest message in dialog etc

Comment: Great! Then this should be a fantastic way of doing that :)

Comment: @DavidK. I think you assume he has a reasonable schema design for his problem

Comment: @Trudbert, you're right in saying that it isn't, but I fully realize that. However, It seems clear to me that he's experimenting with a basic app to get started, and I just want to help him along towards that end.

Answer (score 1):

*Everything done here is mongo console you will have to translate to your driver yourself*

### The easy way

If you want to query for specific conversations add a `conversation_id` to your message (maybe the usernames combined or just a random string) then you can aggregate with

```
db.messages.aggregate({$sort:{date:-1}},
                      {$group:{_id:"$conversation_id", message:{$first:"$$ROOT"}})
```

Or just embed you messages in a conversation document like David K. seems to have thought you where already doing.

### The "I want this to work" way

I build an aggregate that does what you want but you may want to go with the easy way after you see this (maybe someone can think of a shorter one).

First the collection modeled after your schema:

```
> db.chat.find().pretty()
{       "from" : 1,
        "to" : 2,
        "text" : "First from 1 to 2",
        "date" : 1}
{       "from" : 2,
        "to" : 1,
        "text" : "First answer from 2 to 1",
        "date" : 2}
{       "from" : 1,
        "to" : 2,
        "text" : "Second from 1 to 2",
        "date" : 3}
{       "from" : 1,
        "to" : 3,
        "text" : "First 1 to 3",
        "date" : 3}
{       "from" : 3,
        "to" : 1,
        "text" : "Reply 3 to 1",
        "date" : 4}
```

`_id` stipped for readbility and as you see two conversations, one between users `1` and `2` and one between `1` and `3`.

Now the aggregate query:

```
db.chat.aggregate({$project: {to:1,from:1,date:1,text:1,duplicator:{$const: [0,1]}}},
                  {$unwind:"$duplicator"},
                  {$group:{_id:"$_id",
                         parts:{$push:{$cond:[{$eq:"$duplicator",0]},"$from","$to"]}},
                         messages:{$addToSet: {text:"$text",date:"$date"}}}},
                  {$unwind:"$parts"},
                  {$sort:{parts:1}},
                  {$group:{_id:"$_id",
                           parts:{$push:"$parts"},
                           messages:{$first:"$messages"}}},
                  {$sort:{"messages.date":-1}},
                  {$group:{_id:"$parts", last_message:{$first:"$messages"}}})
```

Output:

```
{  "_id" : [1,2],
   "last_message" : [{ "text" : "Second from 1 to 2",
                       "date" : 3 }]
}
{  "_id" : [1,3],
        "last_message" : [{"text" : "Reply 3 to 1",
                           "date" : 4}]
}
```

The last two parts (`$sort` and `$group`) are the same as in the easy way. The rest is to build a `conversation_id` named `parts` for participants. This is done by

- Adding a new array `duplicator`
- Unwinding that array to get a duplicate of each message
- Pushing `to` and `from` in an array `parts` for each message. `parts` will work a conversation_id

Those steps above are inspired [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786686/can-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework-group-return-an-array-of-values/12792579#12792579)

- Then again unwinding `parts`
- to `$sort` them because `[1,2] != [2,1]`
- and `$group` them into one array again

Tose steps result in a conversation id which can then be used like proposed in the two line aggreate above.

### The lesson

Build you schema according to the way you want to query it because raping mongodb with strange aggregates is only fun until it kicks you in the balls in self defense...

---

### The "you formulated your question wrong"

If you just want the last message of a **specific conversation** you could use

```
db.chat.find({to:{$in:[ user1,user2]},from:{$in:[user1,user2]}})
            .sort({date:-1})
            .limit(1)
```