# How to pull an array of JSON objects from API endpoint, to display on angular-nvd3 line chart?

Tags: json, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am trying to get an array of objects from an API endpoint inside of a mongo DB. The trouble I am having is what syntax to use to plug in that data, and then get the chart to display that data from the DB.

Here is my array in the [mongo shell](http://prntscr.com/fjd7yq) and the same shows up in ARC so I know my back-end logic is good, the problem is bring it to the view (on the chart).

The x-axis will display the "_id" (so the dates will show on the bottom), and the y-axis will display the "count".

[Here](http://prntscr.com/fjrr7v) is what I have inside of my controller.

```
vm.lineChartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'cumulativeLineChart',
                height: 450,
                margin: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 60,
                    left: 65
                },
                x: function (d) { return d._id; },
                y: function (d) { return d.count; },

                color: d3.scale.category10().range(),
                duration: 300,
                useInteractiveGuideline: true,
                clipVoronoi: false,

                xAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Reservations',
                    tickFormat: function (d) {
                        return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
                    },
                    showMaxMin: false,
                    staggerLabels: true,
                },

                yAxis: {
                    axisLabel: 'Non-reservations',
                    tickFormat: function (d) {
                        return d3.format('.2')(d);
                    },
                    axisLabelDistance: 20
                },
                xDomain: [vm.xMinValue, vm.xMaxValue],
                yDomain: [customerMetrics.count]
            }
        };
        vm.lineChartData = [
            {
                key: "Reservations",
                values: [[customerMetrics._id, customerMetrics.count]]
                ,
                mean: 250
            }
```

Comment: please include code / output directly in the question (as text) instead of linking to a image

Comment: @woelliJ I added the code.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786686/can-the-mongodb-aggregation-framework-group-return-an-array-of-values

Comment: Have you tried putting a debugger statement above vm.lineChartData and looking at the shape of [[customerMetrics._id, customerMetrics.count]]? That doesn't look right to me. Shouldn't it just be `customerMetrics`?

It should be an array with this shape [{ _id: '...', count: 15 }]